# Two-Sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to understand the Two-Sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test. Somehow no where are good examples connecting math and real example especially having to different distributions. Does someone knows a example to find or can give me one?

I added an example into my question and would like to check whether **I have the same understanding** and **how do I calculate the p-value now**?:

```
ID  Sample X    Sample Y    Cum F(X)    Cum F(Y)    Diff    
1   4           1           0.026490066 0.008196721 0.018293345 
2   28          18          0.21192053  0.155737705 0.056182825 
3   24          25          0.370860927 0.360655738 0.010205189 
4   21          5           0.509933775 0.401639344 0.108294431 
5   23          13          0.662251656 0.508196721 0.154054934 
6   12          7           0.741721854 0.56557377  0.176148084 
7   7           20          0.78807947  0.729508197 0.058571273 
8   23          13          0.940397351 0.836065574 0.104331777 
9   9           20          1           1           0   
Sum 151 122     D-stat  0.176148084 
Count   9   9   D-crit  0.64021448  
                Significance    No  

                No  H_0 the samples come from P,
                Yes H_1 the samples do not come from P
```

To explain in math I did the following:

I have two samples (X and Y) and I would like to test if their distributions are the same.

- $X = Sample$ X
- $Y = Sample$ Y
- $F(X_i) = \frac{X_i}{N};$ Observed
  cumulative frequency distribution of a random sample of n
  observations; (No.of observations ≤ X)/(sum observations)
- $F(Y_i) = \frac{X_i}{N};$ Observed
  cumulative frequency distribution of a random sample of n
  observations; No.of observations ≤ Y)/(sum observations)
- $F(Y_i) = \frac{Y_i}{N};$ Observed
- $n_X = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$; $n_Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{Y_i}$
- $D-stat = max(F(X) - F(Y))$
- $D-cri = c(\alpha)\sqrt(\frac{n_X+n_Y}{n_X*n_Y})$
- Hypothesis check: if D-Stat > D-Crit H0 will be rejected
- 95% significance level, alpha 0.05, $c(\alpha)$ = 1.3581

Comment: Does the example starting on slide 11 [here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~massa/Lecture%2013.pdf) meet your needs?  If not, what more are you looking for?

Comment: @EricTowers I updated my question hope it is more ovious?

Comment: I don't understand how your `Cum F`s aren't multiples of $1/9 = 0.\overline{1}$.

Comment: @EricTowers The linked slides aren't accessible. Can you please share the updated link so that one can understand via another example than the one given in the answer below?

Comment: @Sachin: An updated link is https://www.ime.unicamp.br/~dias/Lecture%2013.pdf .

Answer (score 2):

This process is also described on the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

Construct CDFs:

- Sort. \begin{align*}
  X&: (4, 7, 9, 12, 21, 23, 23, 24, 28)  \\
  Y&: (1, 5, 7, 13, 13, 18, 20, 20, 25)
  \end{align*}
- Construct [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)s.  These should be your `Cum F(...)`s \begin{align*}
  CDF(X) &= \begin{cases}
   0  & \phantom{4\leq{}} x <4 \\
   \frac{1}{9} & 4\leq x<7 \\
   \frac{2}{9} & 7\leq x<9 \\
   \frac{1}{3} & 9\leq x<12 \\
   \frac{4}{9} & 12\leq x<21 \\
   \frac{5}{9} & 21\leq x<23 \\
   \frac{7}{9} & 23\leq x<24 \\
   \frac{8}{9} & 24\leq x<28 \\
   1 & 28 \leq x
  \end{cases}  \\
  CDF(Y) &= \begin{cases}
   0 & \phantom{1\leq{}}x < 1 \\
   \frac{1}{9} & 1\leq x<5 \\
   \frac{2}{9} & 5\leq x<7 \\
   \frac{1}{3} & 7\leq x<13 \\
   \frac{5}{9} & 13\leq x<18 \\
   \frac{2}{3} & 18\leq x<20 \\
   \frac{8}{9} & 20\leq x<25 \\
   1 & 25 \leq x
  \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
  Let's plot these.
  [image: CDFs plotted on same axes]
- Now we compute $|\mathrm{CDF}(X) - \mathrm{CDF}(Y)|$, marking the global maximum.
  $$  |\mathrm{CDF}(X) - \mathrm{CDF}(Y)| = \begin{cases}
    0 & \phantom{1\leq{}}x < 1  \\
   \frac{1}{9} & 1\leq x<4  \\
    0 & 4\leq x<5  \\
   \frac{1}{9} & 5\leq x<9  \\
    0 & 9\leq x<12  \\
   \frac{1}{9} & 12\leq x<18  \\
   \frac{2}{9} & 18\leq x<20  \\
   \frac{4}{9} \ast & 20\leq x<21  \\
   \frac{1}{3} & 21\leq x<23  \\
   \frac{1}{9} & 23\leq x<24  \\
    0 & 24\leq x<25  \\
   \frac{1}{9} & 25\leq x<28  \\
    0 & 28\leq x
  \end{cases}  $$
- So your test statistic is $4/9 = 0.\overline{4}$.  As you have calculated, the critical value at the $\alpha = 0.05$ level is $0.64021{\dots}$.  Since the test statistic is less than the critical value, the null hypothesis (that the two samples are drawn from the same distribution) is not rejected.
- $p$-values are typically either provided by software or found in tables.  For example, `KolmogorovSmirnovTest[]` in Mathematica 11.3 finds the $p$-value for this test statistic for samples of sizes $(9,9)$ is $0.27396{\dots}$.  The R {stats} package implements the test and $p$-value computation in [`ks.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ks.test.html).  Python's SciPy implements these calculations as [`scipy.stats.ks_2samp()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html).  There is even an Excel implementation called [KS2TEST](http://www.real-statistics.com/real-statistics-environment/supplemental-functions/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, do you have any resources for the math behind computing exact p-values like they do in the referenced software? In scipy it seems to abstract the problem to one of counting the number of paths that cross a rectangle that exceeds a given diagonal line. This is quite abstract and I'm not sure how to make the connection back to the test statistic.

Comment: @user2757771 : The answer to your (should be posted to the site as a new) question is *way* beyond the scope of this comment.  Short observation: There is not a "p-value computation".  Each test has its own distribution of test statistic(s), and p-values measure the likelihood of getting a sample drawn from that distribution that is as or more extreme than the statistic we have computed from our real sample.  So you want to compute 1- or 2-tailed integrals depending on the test, sample parameters ("dof", ...), and hypothesis type.  Searching this site for "p-value" finds many examples.